# How do I create a photo gallery with same widths and different heights using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, gallery, photo

I am a beginner to HTML and CSS.  I want to create a photo gallery where all the columns are the same width, but each photo could have a different height.  But I want all the photos to "hug" each other, so that the photos in the second row may not start in the same vertical position as each other.  How do I accomplish that?  Just saw something about columns - maybe that would work?  I'm grateful for any help available!

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is this what you're looking for? http://masonry.desandro.com/ It's jQuery, not only css.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an HTML page which contains `div`s for each column.

You could then either use your CSS stylesheet to place the columns together:
- either float all these column `div` to left (refer to W3C school's [CSS floating](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)), or by
- using `relative` or `absolute` `position`ing (refer to W3C school's [CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)) and give each div an X and Y coordinate.

Then give each column `div` a preset width (refer to W3C school's [CSS width and max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp)).

Every item in a column will then move to a new row (when it has static positioning, which is default for most tags). So just give each image in that column the same fixed with an you should be fine...